# Get 3 column left join based on same one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 column here in tblItem

- purchase
- stock
- calculate

and this 3 column have to join with tblMeasurement

- name

I have tried this, but when I display 3 columns show the same all.

> SQL

```
$sql         = "SELECT A.itemID, A.categoryID, A.purchaseMeasurementID, A.stockMeasurementID, A.calculationMeasurementID, A.itemName, B.itemCategoryName, C.measurementName
                FROM tblPurItem A
                LEFT JOIN tblPurItemCategory B
                ON A.categoryID = B.itemcategoryID
                LEFT JOIN tblPurMeasurement C
                ON A.purchaseMeasurementID= C.measurementID";
```

As you see my sql above, it has join only for purchaseMeasurementID. How do I join stockMeasurementID and calculationMeasurementID based on also tblPurMeasurement ? Is there any missing here?

[image]

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation would all help.

Comment: Okay, I will update more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this `subquery` instead.

```
SELECT A.itemID, A.categoryID, A.purchaseMeasurementID, A.stockMeasurementID, A.calculationMeasurementID, A.itemName
    , (select B.itemCategoryName from tblPurItemCategory B where A.categoryID = B.itemcategoryID limit 1) as itemCategoryName
    , (select C.measurementName from tblPurMeasurement C where A.purchaseMeasurementID= C.measurementID limit 1) as purchasemeasurementName
    , (select C.measurementName from tblPurMeasurement C where A.stockMeasurementID= C.measurementID limit 1) as stockmeasurementName
    , (select C.measurementName from tblPurMeasurement C where A.calculationMeasurementID= C.measurementID limit 1) as calculationmeasurementName
FROM tblPurItem A
```

Comment: How about stockMeasurementID and calculationMeasurementID? The answer you give me, only choose the purchaseMeasurementID.

Comment: i added measurement name for stock and calculation, i think you need to update also your UI

Comment: I'm sorry but when you set there AS purchasemeasurementName, the output get blank which in database no name for column purchasemeasurementName. It has purchaseMeasurementID in main table only.

Comment: In image above, the correct data are in the popup. The wrong data display is get the same data like liter-liter-liter. It should be liter-km-unit.

Comment: need to add your code during binding to your html components.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I have update the javascript. Hope you see it.